# Redirect stdout to a string in Java

Tags: java, stdout

I know how to redirect the stdout to a file, but I have no idea on how to redirect it to a string.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes - you can use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));
```

Then you can get the string with `baos.toString()`.

To specify encoding (and not rely on the one defined by the platform), use the `PrintStream(stream, autoFlush, encoding)` constructor, and `baos.toString(encoding)`

If you want to revert back to the original stream, use:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
```