# Eclipse RCP - Not seeing standard out from 3rd party library on console

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am currently using Eclipse 3.5.2.

I have an Eclipse RCP application that I am developing and I launch it from the Eclipse IDE.

I am writing some code that uses a 3rd party library that I included as a separate Eclipse Plugin.  When I ran my Eclipse RCP app, I don't see the typical output from the 3rd party library on the console tab in the Eclipse IDE.

Is that as expected?  If so is there a way that I can enable that?

Thanks,

Comment: I think, 3rd party lib which you have included as plugin, it will not be activated at the launch of application. A plug in is activated once it has been referenced. You can try to initialize in class of 3rd party lib in Activator.java of your main plug-in. Another check, go to run configuration and see if plug-in you have added is checked or not under required plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the console automatically picks up stdout.

You could, however, redirect stdout to the console's output stream.

See [Redirect stdout to a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183408/redirect-stdout-to-a-string-in-java) for a good example of how to redirect stdout and [How do I write to the console from a plug-in](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F) for information on how to get a stream output for the console.