# How to put System.out.println() in a variable

Tags: java

I have this code here I want to use. I basically want to use string and variable together but save it in a variable

```
Int a = 27;
Int b = 22;
String question = System.out.println("what is " + a + "+" + b);

System.out.println(question);
```

Comment: `String question = "what is " + a + "+" + b + "\n";`

Comment: `String question = "what is " + a + "+" + b;`

Comment: println() method return type is void. In your code you are expecting return value from it eg: "String question = System.out.println("what is " + a + "+" + b);" cause of this conpile time error. try this String question = "what is " + a + "+" + b + "\n";

Comment: Unless you want to do something fancier, in which case you can use [`String::format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Comment: Or String.format("What is %d + %d", a, b);

Comment: Or, `MessageFormat#format()` as: `String question = MessageFormat.format("What is {0} + {1}, a, b)`

Comment: This is what you're Looking for: [Redirect-stdout-to-a-string-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183408/redirect-stdout-to-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily concat strings for a variable like you do it in System.out.println.

So

`String question ="what is " + a + "+" + b;`

would do the job.

Comment: Agreed, but don't forget that question should be of type String!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign the return value of `System.out.println("what is " + a + "+" + b);` to your variable `question`, however, `System.out.println` does not return anything. You have to first creat your variable, and then  print it, like so :

```
Int a = 27;
Int b = 22;
String question = "what is " + a + "+" + b;

System.out.println(question);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the System.out.println() from the string variable question.
So, String question = "what is " + a + "+" + b; 
When u want toask the question print the variable question with System.out.println()

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, Use String concatenation:

```
Int a = 27;
Int b = 22;
String questionStr = "what is " + a + " + " + b;
System.out.println(questionStr);
```